How to Set a Specific Tab as the Initial Route in Expo Router Without an index.tsx?
I'm building a React Native app with Expo Router, organizing it into main sections using a tabs layout: Events, Search, and Profile.
Image of the folder structure im desiring:
Each of those main section Events, Search and Profile are groups inside (tabs) directory.
And each have its own _layout.tsx and a index.tsx 
The RootLayout is currently pointing to (tabs) like so:
function RootLayoutNav() {
    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
    
    return (
        <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
            <Stack>
                <Stack.Screen name='(tabs)' options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            </Stack>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

And this is my _layout inside (tabs):
export default function TabLayout() {
    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
    return (
        <Tabs
            initialRouteName='events'
            screenOptions={{
                tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[ colorScheme ?? 'light' ].tint,
                headerShown: useClientOnlyValue( false, true ),
            }}>
            <Tabs.Screen
                name='events'
                options={{
                    href       : '/events',
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarIcon : ( { color } ) => <TabBarIcon type='Feather' name='calendar' color={color}/>,
                }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name='search'
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarIcon : ( { color } ) => <TabBarIcon type='Feather' name='search' color={color}/>,
                }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name='profile'
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarIcon : ( { color } ) => <TabBarIcon type='Feather' name='user' color={color}/>,
                }}
            />
        </Tabs>
    );
}


here is also EventsLayout, which is exactly the same as SearchLayout and ProfileLayout:
export default function EventsLayout() {
    return (
        <Stack>
            <Stack.Screen
                name='index'
                options={{ title: 'Events', headerLargeTitle: true }}
            />
        </Stack>
    );
}

While this structure seems correct, the app doesn't render events as the initial tab on load. Instead, the not-found.tsx is triggered due to the absence of an index.tsx in the (tabs) directory. I wish to avoid having an index.tsx inside (tabs) and prefer using nested groups as they are.
Question:
How can I make the app load with the events group as the initial view without needing an index.tsx in the (tabs) directory? Is there a configuration in Expo Router that allows for this setup?
I have tried looking up the solution on Expo Docs and various other forums but to no avail I have not found the answer.

Did some research and here is the solution:
in the app directory and a file index.tsx, this will be the 1st screen rendered which will redirect user to events tab screen, Also note that /events should be the folder name containing the index.tsx of the events
import { Redirect } from 'expo-router';
import React from 'react';

const MainScreen = () => {
  return <Redirect href="/(tabs)/events" />;
};

export default MainScreen;


while this is great and works fine and you mentioned you want to avoid having an index.tsx but i think u can have nested group as they are but only have to name the one you want to load first as index so the folder will be named as index folder and i think the initialRouteName will pick it up

Foreword
I also ended up in the same scenario, I was trying to have multiple sub-navigators under (tabs)/.
In other words, I wanted to turn the "index" route into a folder so that sub-routes could be grouped within it, whilst having the "index" route maintain its own name.

I created my app with the "Navigation" template:
npx create-expo-app --template
(Selecting: "Navigation (TypeScript)")
The template's starting app/ structure:

app/
├── (tabs)/
|   ├── _layout.tsx
|   ├── index.tsx
|   ├── two.tsx
├── _layout.tsx
├── +html.tsx
├── +not-found.tsx
├── modal.tsx

Solution
After moving app/(tabs)/index.tsx elsewhere, my app always started on +not-found.tsx page, navigating around the app after that was fine (but it was far from ideal!), here's how I solved it:

Set up the following structure in app/(tabs)/:
This structure allowed me to set up sub-navigators for each tab ("account", "browse", and "collection").
Note: The tabs could equally just be files called account.tsx, browse.tsx, and collection.tsx (but this would mean that it would work "out-the-box" if collection.tsx were named index.tsx (as the template initially had)

app/
├── (tabs)/
|   ├── account/
|   |   ├── _layout.tsx
|   |   ├── index.tsx
|   |   ├── ...
|   ├── browse/
|   |   ├── _layout.tsx
|   |   ├── index.tsx
|   |   ├── ...
|   ├── collection/
|   |   ├── _layout.tsx
|   |   ├── index.tsx
|   |   ├── ...
|   ├── _layout.tsx
|   ├── index.tsx
├── _layout.tsx
├── +html.tsx
├── +not-found.tsx
├── modal.tsx


Edit app/(tabs)/index.tsx:
Initially, app/(tabs)/index.tsx contained the template's "index" route with a component called TabOneScreen.
I had to delete this so that the "index" route would always redirect to the "collection" tab.

// app/(tabs)/index.tsx

import { Redirect } from "expo-router";

const Index = () => {
  return <Redirect href="/collection" />;
};
export default Index;


Hide the "index" tab in app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx:
After step 2, there was an extra Tab in the Tab Bar (from app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx), to fix that I hid the item.

// app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx

<Tabs>
  <Tabs.Screen
    name="index"
    options={{
      tabBarItemStyle: { display: "none" },
    }}
  />
  <Tabs.Screen name="browse" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="collection" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="account" />
</Tabs>

Not much about this file is different from the template's original (mostly the name prop for each Tabs.Screen - which is pointing to the file/folder names). Here's the full file:
// app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx

import React from "react";
import FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
import Colors from "@/constants/Colors";
import { useColorScheme } from "@/hooks/useColorScheme";
import { useClientOnlyValue } from "@/hooks/useClientOnlyValue";


// You can explore the built-in icon families and icons on the web at https://icons.expo.fyi/
function TabBarIcon(props: {
  name: React.ComponentProps<typeof FontAwesome>["name"];
  color: string;
}) {
  return <FontAwesome size={28} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} {...props} />;
}

export default function TabLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? "light"].tint,
        // Disable the static render of the header on web
        // to prevent a hydration error in React Navigation v6.
        headerShown: useClientOnlyValue(false, true),
      }}
    >
      {/**
       * Index is required for routing
       * Hidden with the redirect fixes the issue
       */}
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          tabBarItemStyle: { display: "none" },
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen name="browse" />
      <Tabs.Screen name="collection" />
      <Tabs.Screen name="account" />
    </Tabs>
  );
}


TL;DR
index.tsx is needed, but you can make it redirect to the desired tab and hide "index" from in the Tabs component.

In my example, the "index" route was called "collection".
I moved app/(tabs)/index.tsx to app/(tabs)/collection/index.tsx

This meant I had to re-add app/(tabs)/index.tsx with Redirect to make "collection" the default route.




I had the exact same structure minus the index.tsx with the redirect...added that, and everything is working now. Thanks!

I ran into the exact same problem today, and I couldn't get things to work properly using the existing answer. Fortunately, I did stumble on the "correct" solution in the official Expo Router docs – the key, in your case, would be to use (events) instead of events as the folder name. So, rename the folder, and change the tab name –
(tabs)/_layout.tsx:
export default function TabLayout() {
    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
    return (
        <Tabs
            screenOptions={{
                tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[ colorScheme ?? 'light' ].tint,
                headerShown: useClientOnlyValue( false, true ),
            }}>
            <Tabs.Screen
                name='(events)'
                // ...
    );
}

